# Is bin folder necessary to upload in domain?

Tags: asp.net, bin

I have just uploaded my web application in my domain. Is bin folder also necessary to be uploaded in Domain ??

Comment: Give more details what are you talking and asking about, please. What application, what domain, why do you upload and where, etc.

Comment: Yes if it has any third party DLL that you are using and that doesn't resides in GAC of your server.

Comment: Yes, it contains all your dlls...

Comment: It would all depend whats installed on the server. For example, asp.net MVC can either be installed on the server or bin-deployed. Its hard to answer without extra details. You'll definitely need a bin folder with some DLL's, but which ones depends on the target environment

Comment: If it is published websited or if you have used any third party dll like `Ajax Toolkit, URL Rewriter, etc..` then it is compulsory.

Comment: A quick way you could have answered the question yourself would be to upload without a bin folder and see if the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally .net puts some required DLLs into the bin folder and these must be uploaded. It is possible change the location of these, however, so it is possible to do without the bin folder.